# Python iterate and write to second file

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to iterate through a tab delimited text file and write rows that contain a certain value to a second text file. My attempt is below. Calling print(line) on the original file after line three prints the correct rows, and I get the same issue 151 message (shown below) when I use open & close instead of with so I'm assuming the problem relates to the way I've used file.write(line). I'm pretty new at this...

```
with open("file_1.idx", "r") as file_1:
    for line in file_1:
        if "abc" in line:
            with open("file_2.rtf", "w") as file_2:
                file_2.write(line)


151
151
151
```

Comment: You don't describe your problem -- what's the issue?

Comment: I get an issue 151 message and a file_2 that cannot be opened.

Comment: Please add the message / error trace.

Comment: please post the full stack trace. where does this `151` come from? there is no `print` statement.

Comment: The 151 is auto-generated as an error message would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you reopen (and overwrite) the second file. this should work:

```
with open("file_1.idx", "r") as file_1, open("file_2.rtf", "w") as file_2:
    for line in file_1:
        if "abc" in line:
            file_2.write(line)
```

Comment: I understand what you mean by reopening (and overwriting) with each iteration, but I still get the issue 151 message and a file_2 that cannot be opened.

Comment: for the write problem: do you have write permissions in your workdir? and maybe consider using absolute paths for your 2 files.
by the way: this way you can only read and write text files; python will not magically write `.rtf`.

Comment: The code above will create the new file_2, and I'm using my personal laptop, so I believe I have adequate permissions. I've used the path beginning with "/Users/myname/..." for each file not just the local name.

Comment: again: none of the code displayed here will print `151` to the console. is there more code around it? and what exactly is the remaining problem? does python print a traceback? please post that! what do you mean with *auto-generated*?

Comment: I realized it's not actually an error message, but the length of each line (number of characters). I've included all the code above. The problem is that nothing is printed to the second file. Python creates the second file, but it cannot be opened.

Comment: *cannot be opened*? if your process can write it, you will be able to open it. but open it with a simple text editor; just double-clicking it will probably try to open it as `.rtf` - which the file is not.

Comment: It was indeed readable, but, as you postulate, not as a .rtf. I changed the code to write to a .txt file and that worked. Thanks hiro